# Convergence of sequence of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

[image]

For part (a) $n^{s} = e^{s \log n}$ and $e^{s \log n}$ is holomorphic as it is differentiable, $\frac{{{d}{\left({e}^{x}\right)}}}{{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}}={e}^{x}$.

But I am unable to proceed for part (b) onwards. I am not sure what properties or results to use. It'll be nice if someone could help me out.

Comment: Hint: in $\mathbb{C}$, absolute convergence of a series implies convergence.

Comment: @BrunoB that probably fixes part (b). What about (c) and (d)?

Comment: Same hint for $(c)$: normal convergence implies uniform convergence. However now you dispose of a compact set: what can you say about the function $s \mapsto \operatorname{Re}(s)$ on said compact?